# JavaScriptでPNG画像などのデータをバイナリ形式で取得したい

Tags: javascript, html, html5, 画像

FileReader.readAsText()のサンプルを試して動作させているのですが、PNG画像を選択すると文字化けしてしまいます。
文字化けしないようにするにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

やりたいことは、PNG画像のデータを以下のようなバイナリ形式で受け取り、これをそのままデータベースに保存したいです。データはサーバ側でPythonを動作させているのでそちらで受け取りたいです。

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\....
```

使用するOS MacOS High Sierra
ブラウザはchromeバージョン 88.0.4324.150です。
よろしくお願いします。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    div#result { white-space: pre-wrap ; }
    input { width: 95% ; font-size: 16px ; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" multiple id="hoge">
<hr>
    <div id="result"></div>
<script>
var element = document.getElementById( "hoge" ) ;
var resultElement = document.getElementById( "result" ) ;

element.onchange = function () {
    var fileReader = new FileReader() ;

    fileReader.onload = function () {
        console.log( this.result ) ;
        resultElement.appendChild( new Text( this.result ) ) ;
    }

    var file = element.files[0] ;
    fileReader.readAsText( file ) ;
//  fileReader.readAsBinaryString( file ) ; // 試してみよう！
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### 参照

https://lab.syncer.jp/Web/API_Interface/Reference/IDL/FileReader/readAsText/

Answer (score 1):

`readAsText()` はテキストを読み込むためのものなので、テキストではないPNG画像に使っても意味がありません。

画像ファイルのバイナリをサーバに送るには、一般的にはフォームに含めて `multipart/form-data` タイプで送信します。

＊ フォームの場合

```html
<body>
  <form action="...." enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" multiple id="hoge" name="files">
  </form>
<hr>
<script>
var element = document.getElementById("hoge");
element.onchange = function() {
    element.form.submit();
};
</script>
</body>
```

＊ XHRの場合

```html
<body>
  <input type="file" multiple id="hoge"
<hr>
<script>
var element = document.getElementById("hoge");
element.onchange = function() {
    let fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('files', element.files[0]);
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '....');
    xhr.send(fd);
};
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。PNGファイルを受け取りたい場合はどうしたら良いのでしょうか？

Comment: PNGファイルを読み込んだ結果をどうしたいのでしょうか?

Comment: こういったバイナリ形式で受け取りたいです。`b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\....`これをそのままデータベースに保存したいんです。

Comment: どこで受け取るという話でしょうか? ウェブサーバ?

Comment: はいサーバ側でPythonを動作させているのでそちらで受け取りたいです。

Comment: サーバ側でどういうAPIを持っているかわかりませんが、一般的には FormData にファイルをそのまま追加(`formData.append('name', element.files[0])`)して`multipart/form-data` タイプで送信すればサーバ側でバイナリのまま取得可能です。

Comment: ここまでの内容を質問文に反映させて頂きました。コメントでのやり取りが長くなりそうな場合は[チャット](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ja.stackoverflow.com)のご利用を検討して頂くか、質問文や回答を適切に更新してみてください。

Comment: それってサーバに送る前にJavaScript側でconsole.log等でバイナリ文字列を表示することは可能でしょうか？

Comment: バイナリをコンソールに表示することに意味はないと思います。

Comment: バイナリを見ることは可能なのでしょうか？それともセキュリティ的にそのような仕様になってないということでしょうか？

Comment: 16進ダンプしたりbase64したりで何とか読める形にはできますけども、人間が目視しても意味のあることではないと思います。なぜ見たいのでしょうか。

Comment: 好奇心で実際に画像はこうなっているのかと確認してみたかったので、質問しました。

Comment: 中身を見てみたいだけでしたら、macOS には `od` コマンドが添付されているので、ターミナルで `od -t x1 ファイル名` などすればよいです。

Comment: Pythonのopen等で画像が文字列になっているのは知っていて、出来ればJavaScript上で見てみたかったのですが、解答する事を渋ってるように伺えるのですが、質問的によくないのでしょうか？

Comment: セキュリティ上難しい場合は今までの解答で大丈夫です。とても丁寧に助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: セキュリティの問題などはありません。JavaScript上で人間が読める状態にすることは可能ですが、何の役にも立たないので具体的な方法を書きたくないのです。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございました。